# Fortran memory allocation does not give an error, but the program is killed by OS at initialization

Tags: memory-management, fortran

Given the minimal working example provided below, do you know why the memory allocation error does not occur at memory allocation step? As I checked, when I use valgrind to run the code, or add parameter source=0.0 to memory allocation statement, then I have, as expected, the memory allocation error.

Update: I reproduced the issue with minimal working example:

```
 program memory_test

  implicit none

  double precision, dimension(:,:,:,:), allocatable :: sensitivity
  double precision, allocatable :: sa(:)
  double precision, allocatable :: sa2(:)

  integer :: ierr,nnz
  integer :: nx,ny,nz,ndata

  nx = 50
  ny = 50
  nz = 100
  ndata = 1600

  allocate(sensitivity(nx,ny,nz,ndata),stat=ierr)

  sensitivity = 1.0

  nnz = 100000000

  !allocate(sa(nnz),source=dble(0.0),stat=ierr)
  allocate(sa(nnz),stat=ierr)
  if(ierr /= 0) print*, 'Memory error!'

  !allocate(sa2(nnz),source=dble(0.0),stat=ierr)
  allocate(sa2(nnz),stat=ierr)
  if(ierr /= 0) print*, 'Memory error!'

  print*, 'Start initialization'

  sa = 0.0
  sa2 = 0.0

  print*, 'End initialization'

end program memory_test
```

When I run it I have no message 'Memory error!' printed, but have message 'Start initialization' and then the program is killed by OS. If I use memory allocation with 'source' parameter (as commented in the code) only then I have message 'Memory error!'.

For memory statistics, the 'free' command gives me this output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8169952    3630284    4539668      46240       1684     124888
-/+ buffers/cache:    3503712    4666240
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum working example?

Comment: At which number are you looking when determining the memory usage? Are you aware of the differences between resident/physical/virtual/shared memory?

Comment: I am looking at the number given by Ubuntu utils System load indicator.

Comment: The point is that the memory allocation and initialization of the array are well separated in the code. And the initialization is done slowly, since it involves some heavy computations. And I can see that during this slow initialization process the memory grows till 8 Gb. Then I tried to put initialization with constant (zero) right after memory allocation and still notice similar behavior, just it takes less time to initialize.

Comment: The most weird point is that I do not get any error (via  stat=ierr) during the memory allocation step. But the program  gets killed by OS (perhaps signal 9) during the initialization.

Comment: This is the minimal example to show approximately what I am doing. In real code I have more arrays etc. I am now trying to reproduce similar behavior with minimal example.

Comment: I just tried to run the program with valgrind and then I get the error during the memory allocation step (using stat=ierr parameter), as expected. But for some reasons error does not occur when I simply run the program, and it occurs only during value assignments, when the resident memory is increasing. Can this issue be related to the fact that I am running Ubuntu in virtual box on my desktop?

Comment: I also tried valgrind, which says 4,400,002,569 bytes allocated (where I removed MPI). gfortran says no array temporaries in this case. RE virtual box, is there any setting for memory allocation limit...?

Comment: I just reproduced the issue with minimal working example. Please see the updated message with code.

Comment: In your new code, sensitivity first allocates 3.2 GB, then sa and sa2 allocate 0.8 * 2 = 1.6 GB, so totaling 4.8 GB. valgrind says "4,806,002,569 bytes allocated", so looks consistent (and the program runs well on my machine). Hmm... I guess isn't it a problem of virtual box...??

Comment: I think one would need to modify the numbers to set the allocatable memory higher than free memory. The issue is that allocate statement does not give the error, when memory exceeds the limit.

Comment: Please note that allocate() does not actually allocate physical memory when invoked. In practice, physical memory is given from the OS when actual assignment is attempted by Fortran program. So the error occurs when the program hits the assignment statement like xyz(:) = 0.0. Btw, I wonder you may be using about 3.2 GB memory for other applications in your virtual box (for browser etc?). Then Fortran needs 4.8 GB, so alltogether >= 8 GB, exceeding the limit of virtual-box setting...? (just my guess).

Comment: Though I am not very familiar with OS stuff, this article may be useful http://www.darkcoding.net/software/resident-and-virtual-memory-on-linux-a-short-example/

Comment: Hi Roy, thank you for your comments and the article, Just to answer your previous comment -- yes I am exceeding the memory limits, but then I would expect to have an error from allocate statement, otherwise how else I can know that? Plus I decreased the minimal working example. Interestingly, if I instead of having arrays sa and sa2, make one array sa of twice size (so total the same memory consumption), then I get the error from the allocate statement.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. And yeah, I also want to know more detail about the precise behavior of stat=ierr in allocate(), because it was practically useless in your case...

Comment: As for source=0.0 in allocate(), it probably requests the OS to give actual physical memory, so resulting in an error. If so, it might be useful to attach source=0.0 to all important allocate() to ensure physical-memory allocation.

Comment: @Vitaliy when you exhaust your memory limit the kernel [OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) starts killing things and this may be why your program is dying.  There should be system log messages if the OOM killer is active so you can look there to verify.  The only fix for that is 1) use smaller arrays or 2) get more memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are seeing the behavior of the memory allocation strategy linux uses.  When you allocate memory but have not written to it, it is solely contained in virtual memory (note this may also be affected by the particular Fortran runtime library, but I'm not sure).  This memory exists in your process virtual address space but it is not backed by any actual physical memory pages.  Only when you write to the memory will physical pages be allocated and only enough to satisfy the write.

Consider the following program:

```
program test
   implicit none
   real,allocatable :: array(:) 

   allocate(array(1000000000)) !4 gb array

   print *,'Check memory - 4 GB allocated'
   read *

   array(1:1000000) = 1.0

   print *,'Check memory - 4 MB assigned'
   read *

   array(1000000:100000000) = 2.0

   print *,'Check memory - 400 MB assigned'
   read *

   array = 5.0

   print *,'Check memory - 4 GB assigned'
   read *

end program
```

This program allocates 4 GB of memory then writes to a 4 MB array section,  a 396 MB array section (total writes = 400 MB) and finally writes to the full array (total writes = 4 GB).  The program pauses between each write so you can take a look at memory usage.

After the allocate, before the first write:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                           
29192 casey     20   0 3921188   1176   1052 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 fortranalloc
```

All of the memory is virtual (VIRT), only a small bit is backed by physical memorory (RES).

After the 4 MB write:

```
29192 casey     20   0 3921188   5992   1984 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 fortranalloc
```

after the 396 MB write:

```
29192 casey     20   0 3921188 392752   1984 S   0.0  1.6   0:00.18 fortranalloc
```

and after the 4 GB write:

```
29192 casey     20   0 3921188 3.727g   1984 S  56.6 15.8   0:01.88 fortranalloc
```

Note that after each write the resident memory increases to satisfy the write.  This shows you that actual physical memory allocation only occurs on write, not merely on allocation, thus the normal `allocate()` has no way to detect error.  When you add the `source` parameter to `allocate` then a write occurs and this causes full physical allocation of the memory and this if this fails, the error can be detected.

What you are likely seeing is the linux [OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) which is invoked when memory is exhausted.  When this occurs the OOM Killer will use an algorithm to determine what to kill to free up memory, and the behavior of your code makes it a very likely candidate to be killed.  When your write causes physical allocation that can be met, your process is being killed by the kernel.  You see it on write (caused by assignment) but not allocation because of the behavior detailed above.

Comment: Casey, thanks for very informative answer! One thing I do not understand is that if I use one array sa, instead of sa and sa2, in my example, and allocate it with twice larger the number of elements (which should give same total amount of memory consumption), then actually the error occurs during the memory allocation step, as expected. Furthermore, it was not straightforward to reproduce the issue, since most of the times when I allocate large amount of memory I have an allocation error. Seems only in particular situations it is possible to allocate more memory than physically available.

Comment: @vitaliy in any case your root problem is a lack of memory. If you want arrays that big, get more of it.

Answer (score 4):

Extended comment rather than an answer:

In Fortran initialization has a specific meaning; it refers to setting a variable's value at declaration.  So this

```
real :: myvar = 0.0
```

is initialization.  While these

```
real :: myvar
....
myvar = 0.0
```

are not.  Now, perhaps more relevant to the issue you report, this statement

```
isensit%sa(:) = 0.0
```

assigns the value `0.0` to every element of the **array section** `isensit%sa(:)`.  This is very (once you get used to it) different to what I think you meant to write, which is:

```
isensit%sa = 0.0
```

This version assigns the value `0.0` to every element of the **array** `isensit%sa`.  Because an array section, even one comprising every element of the array, is not the array, Fortran compiler's may temporarily allocate space for the section while it processes the assignment.  This probably makes sense when you think about a more general array section.

I'm not sure I understand why you think the space isn't allocated when the `allocate` statement executes but I suggest you sort out the assignment, then think again.  And I guess that the temporary allocation of space for the array section, which will be as much space as the array itself consumes, might tip your program over the edge and cause the behaviour you report.

Incidentally, you might try the statement

```
allocate(isensit%sa(isensit%nnz),source=0.0,stat=ierr)
```

which should, if your compiler is bang up to date, do the allocation and set the values in the array in one statement.

Oh, and an entirely gratuitous remark: prefer `use mpi` (or `use mpi_mod` or whatever your installation prefers to `include mpif.h`.  This will forestall (many) errors which might arise from mismatching calls to mpi routines with their requirements.  Use-association of the routines means that the compiler can check argument matching, inclusion of a header file does not.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. I am trying to test your suggestions. Remark about 'use mpi'. This is done on purpose, knowing all possible issues with such approach. The reason is that some systems have no 'module load' system, which is common.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thank you for noticing the "source=0.0" parameter! Now, when I add this parameter I have memory allocation error, as expected! Without this flag there is no error from allocation and the program is being killed by the OS during the initialization (value assignment) step! This is weird and confirms my previous observations. Any ideas why? Or where to look at?

Comment: When I initialize the whole array as you suggested, I have the same behavior, i.e., no error during memory allocation and program is killed during the initialization process. And as I said I can clearly see how memory consumption grows up during the initialization, it grows from 4 Gb to 8 Gb.

Comment: I just reproduced the issue with minimal working example. Please see the updated message with code.

Comment: I modified the code to assign to arrays and also have decreased the minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a comparison of three methods for invoking `allocate()`:

```
program mem_test
    implicit none
    integer, allocatable :: a(:,:,:)
    integer ierr, n1, n2, L, method

    n1 = 250000 ; n2 = 1000    !! 1-GB subarray

    print *, "Input: method, L"
    read *, method, L

    select case ( method )
    case ( 1 )
        allocate( a( n1, n2, L ) )              !! request L-GB virtual mem
    case ( 2 )
        allocate( a( n1, n2, L ), stat=ierr )   !! request L-GB virtual mem
        if ( ierr /= 0 ) stop "Memory error!"
    case ( 3 )
        allocate( a( n1, n2, L ), source=0 )    !! request L-GB resident mem
    endselect

    print *, "allocate() passed (type any key)"
    read *
end
```

The machine used here is Linux(x86_64) with 64-GB physical memory and 64-GB swap disk. `ulimit -v` shows "unlimited". In all cases (`method` = 1,2,3) the program raised an error for `L` > ~ 120, i.e. the sum of physical and swap memory. For `method` = 1,3, the system raised an error

```
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Allocation would exceed memory limit
```

whereas for `method` = 2, `stat=ierr` detected an error. For `L` < 120 the program continues to run, where `method` = 2 starts to write a huge amount of 0... Anyway, on this machine, the maximum amount of memory allowed for `allocate()` seems to be limited by the physical + swap size (a reasonable result), although `ulimit -v` shows unlimited virtual memory.

---

Below is another test for limiting the maximum amount of memory allowed for `allocate()` using `ulimit -v`. This program allocates 4GB array and assigns a value to 2GB.

```
program alloc_test
    implicit none
    real, allocatable :: a(:), b(:)
    integer ierr, n

    n = 500000000

    allocate( a( n ), stat=ierr )   !! requests 2GB virtual memory
    if ( ierr /= 0 ) stop "Memory error! (a)"

    allocate( b( n ), stat=ierr )   !! requests 2GB virtual memory
    if ( ierr /= 0 ) stop "Memory error! (b)"

    print *, "before assignment (type any key)"
    call system( "ps aux | grep a.out" )
    read *

    print *, "now writing values..."
    a(:) = 0.0    !! request 2GB resident memory                        

    print *, "after assignment (type any key)"
    call system( "ps aux | grep a.out" )
    read *
end
```

If I do `./a.out` directly, this program runs without stopping at `allocate()`. We now limit virtual memory to 1GB based on [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28678/how-to-limit-available-virtual-memory-per-process)

```
$ ( ulimit -v 1000000 ; ./a.out )
```

then we have

```
STOP Memory error! (a)
```

If we limit it to 2.2 GB

```
STOP Memory error! (b)
```

Finaly, if we set it to >4GB, the assignment begins

```
before assignment (type any key)
<username>    12380  0.0  0.0 3918048  652 pts/1    S+   07:59   0:00 ./a.out

now writing values...

after assignment (type any key)
<username>    12380 38.0  2.9 3918048 1953788 pts/1 S+   07:59   0:00 ./a.out
```

So we can limit the amount of virtual memory (if necessary) such that `allocate( ..., stat=ierr )` raises an error against overallocation.

Comment: Good point! It would be also interesting to know in what situations the allocate() does not invoke an error if allocated memory is larger than physically available.

Comment: It looks that for my Linux, "ulimit -a" shows virtual memory to be unlimited, so essentially infinite memory allowed ?(as long as 64-bit pointer can represent) Also, I can't understand why the above program requires only 1.9GB physical memory (rather than 2.0 GB).

Comment: In other words, allocate( stat=ierr ) never signals an error in usual Linux environment??? Hmm... this also sounds strange :(

Comment: Can you try to allocate large amount of virtual memory to confirm that in your system allocate does not signal an error?

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed strange behavior of the allocate() function. I do not remember such issues with "new" operator in C++.

Comment: @roygvib 2 billion != (2**31 == 2GiB), which is why you only see 1.9 GiB.

Comment: @Vitaliy I added some more comparison of allocate() (see above). It seems the maximum amount is limited by physical + swap size (as expected). I first thought that allocation of virtual memory over 160GB is allowed, but it looks like my mistake... Just for additional info :)